# Regular expression for search and replace in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, regex

I need to do a search and replace for the text below in Microsoft Word.

> Skill No 24:

And replace it with:

> Skill No: 24

What should the syntax be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could find:

```
Skill No ([0-9]{1,}):
```

And replace with:

```
Skill No: \1
```

Don't forget to check 'Use wildcards'

Comment: If your Word installation is done in a culture *different* from enUS, Word kindly changes the separator in regular expressions, so that above will become `Skill No ([0-9]{1;}):`.  Notice the comma vs semicolon.

Comment: @MyICQ Ah, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
Skill No (\d+):
```

Replace:

```
Skill No: \1
```

Comment: in `MS-WORD` `\d` dosent mean a digit.